# Nodes/Relationships created but not being reflected on browser in neo4j version 3.2

Tags: neo4j

I am facing some issue with my neo4j browser . I am able to create a nodes/ relationship . When I used MATCH and RETURN queries it gives me the precise results .

But whatever I am creating , not being reflected on neo4j browser under the labels and relationship field . I think it's a configuration issue from my side , but not sure.

Please reply with your suggestions/answers .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the exactly meaning of "reflected on neo4j browser under the labels and relationship field"?

Comment: while creating did you used return statement?

Comment: Please add the CREATE (?) statement you are using and what you would then expect to see.

Comment: Apparently you do not return the result when adding data.

Comment: I do not know why , but I reinstalled neo4j and it worked fine for me ,